# Identify it then Move It (Macro)

Tags: vba, excel

I had this project in Chemistry to supply a list of Compound elements
now I had found a website where it gives me a very long list of elements:

[image: this will be the references]

I had made this Code but it Doesn't Work

```
Sub move()
    Dim list As Range
    Set list = Range("A1:A2651")

    For Each Row In list.Rows
            If (Row.Font.Regular) Then
                Row.Cells(1).Offset(-2, 1) = Row.Cells(1)
            End If
    Next Row
End Sub
```

Can you make it run for me? you can have your own algorithm ofc.

Comment: Please share the website URL. Describe what means "it Doesn't Work"?

Comment: https://quizlet.com/18087424/a-long-long-list-of-chemical-compounds-and-their-names-flash-cards/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the list is constantly in the same format (i.e. Compound name, empty line, Compound Symbols, empty line) this quick code will work:

```
Sub move()
Dim x As Integer
    x = 3
With ActiveSheet
    Do Until x > 2651
        .Cells(x - 2, 2).Value = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        .Cells(x, 1).ClearContents
        x = x + 4
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

After running you can then just sort columns A:B to remove the blanks.

After trying your original code I realised the problem was with the .regular property value. I've not seen .regular before, so swapped it to NOT .bold instead, and to ignore blank entries, then added the line for clearing the contents of the cell copied. This is most like the original code for reference:

```
Sub get_a_move_on()
    Dim list As Range
    Set list = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A2561")

    For Each Row In list.Rows
            If Row.Font.Bold = False And Row.Value <> "" Then
                Row.Cells(1).Offset(-2, 1) = Row.Cells(1)
                Row.Cells(1).ClearContents
            End If
    Next Row
End Sub
```

P.S it's a list of compounds, not elements, there's only about 120 elements in the periodic table! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to retrieve the data you need via XHR and RegEx:

```
Sub GetChemicalCompoundsNames()

    Dim sRespText As String
    Dim aResult() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' retrieve HTML content
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://quizlet.com/18087424", False
        .Send
        sRespText = .responseText
    End With
    ' regular expression for rows
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "qWord[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)<[\s\S]*?qDef[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)<"
        With .Execute(sRespText)
            ReDim aResult(1 To .Count, 1 To 2)
            For i = 1 To .Count
                With .Item(i - 1)
                    aResult(i, 1) = .SubMatches(0)
                    aResult(i, 2) = .SubMatches(1)
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With
    ' output to the 1st sheet
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        Output .Range("A1"), aResult
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)
    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
            UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
            UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1 _
        )
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
            .Columns.AutoFit
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Gives output (663 rows total):

[image: output]